# Android 10 Activity onCreate Crash

Tags: android, android-10.0

The splash activity of my app works well on all devices except on an Android 10 device that I have just recently updated.

**Here is my code:**

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid() != null)
      startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
    else
      startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));

    finish();
  }

}
```

I have also tried navigating directly to `HomeActiviy` or `LoginActivity` but still  crashes when I try to run on an Android 10 device

```
Error occurs when calling super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

2020-01-17 13:58:25.527 23561-23561/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: rickroydaban.projects.android.memorise, PID: 23561
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rickroydaban.projects.android.memorise/rickroydaban.android.memorise.ui.SplashScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment.setProcessListener(androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment$ActivityInitializationListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3448)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment.setProcessListener(androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment$ActivityInitializationListener)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner$3.onActivityCreated(ProcessLifecycleOwner.java:162)
        at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated(Application.java:392)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityCreated(Activity.java:1232)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:1513)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:81)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:149)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:313)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
        at rickroydaban.android.memorise.ui.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

Has anyone able to fix [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHlUG.png) issue?

Comment: There is some issue in ReportFragment. Please check or debug

Comment: seems like your fragment is null!

Comment: Can you add the dependencies in build.gradle(app) with your question? The problem may be due to the new androidx library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141536990), this will occur when using `lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0` (usually through a transitive dependency on Fragment or AppCompat) and `lifecycle-process:2.1.0` (usually through a transitive dependency on `lifecycle-extensions`).

There are a number of work arounds available in the bug:

> You do any one of the following:
>
> - Add an explicit dependency on `lifecycle-process:2.2.0-alpha05` to pull in the new version that is compatible with `lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0-alpha05`
> - Upgrade your `lifecycle:extensions` dependency to `2.2.0-alpha05` so that `lifecycle-process` is upgraded
> - Remove the `lifecycle:extensions` dependency entirely and use only the lifecycle libraries you need (for example, use `lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx` if you want ViewModels) so that you don't pull in `lifecycle-process` at all

Or, since the compatibility issue has been fixed in a later release, upgrade to a later version of Fragments (version `1.2.0-beta01` or higher) or Lifecycle `2.2.0-beta01` or higher if you directly depend on Lifecycle.

Comment: This helped me to solve my issue, so I updated my app gradle from androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0-alpha05 to the latest version androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0-rc03 and that's it